# Typescript/Angular - Call separate function after modal result return

Tags: angularjs, typescript, bootstrap-modal, angular-promise, angular-bootstrap

I'm having an issue calling a separate function when my promise is returned by closing or canceling a modal in Angular/Typescript. Perhaps I'm trying to do something impossible but all the examples I've seen either log the returned data back to console or to a variable or throws up an alert. Like so:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

What I'm looking to do is call a *separate* function once that result is returned, like:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    this.EditWidget(result);
});
```

But this doesn't work and I can't seem to figure out why. I've tried about everything and I guess I'm just missing something about how the promise works here.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong the code you have posted. What makes you think the error is there? Does that function work outside of the promise? Can you provide more of the code to show what all you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gess is that `this` is not what you expect it to be. You need to capture the value of this and use the captured value in the callback:

```
var that = this;
modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    that.EditWidget(result);
});
```

or to bind the function to this:

```
var callback = function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    this.EditWidget(result);
};

modalInstance.result.then(callback.bind(this));
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much!